# vm fusion only allows 40gb drive for windows7, can I create another drive?

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion, virtual-drive

When installing windows 7 on my mac book pro using VMware fusion fusion, it says I can set a 40gb maximum size for the virtual machine drive image.

Can I create another drive and link it to the vm, and change other settings such as memory allocation later?

Answer (score 1):

If you have yet to complete the installation and are at the window where it shows the Virtual Machine Summary with the specifications you have listed, you should be able to change the VM disk size and allocated RAM by clicking the *Customize Settings* button.

Once clicked, you'll first need to choose a location for the new virtual machine, which defaults to the ~/Documents/Virtual Machines folder. After that, you can change all kinds of settings including disk size and RAM.